# Merging rows with similar data, concatenating differentiating values into separate cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have found similar questions answered, but I have a minor difference.

**Note**: this is for thousands of cells.

I am attempting to merge similar TimeDate/Productname/Username rows, but give differentiating tag values their own cell ( TimeDate , Productname, Username, and TagValue are each their own column of cells).

[Image of what is required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U4LJ.png)

Update: I merged the first three columns, so that it is easier to compare. I have code that does the job, but combines tag values into one cell instead of separate. How can I get this code to place the tag values in separate, adjacent, cells?

```
Sub CombineRows()
      'Update 20131202
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Dic As Variant
Dim arr As Variant
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
 Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address,    Type:=8)
Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  arr = WorkRng.Value
For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
xvalue = arr(i, 1)
If Dic.Exists(xvalue) Then
    Dic(arr(i, 1)) = Dic(arr(i, 1)) & " " & arr(i, 2)
Else
    Dic(arr(i, 1)) = arr(i, 2)
End If
      Next
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       WorkRng.ClearContents
       WorkRng.Range("A1").Resize(Dic.Count, 1) =          Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.keys)
      WorkRng.Range("B1").Resize(Dic.Count, 1) =   Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.items)
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.  IF you have existing code that is not working we will help overcome specific problems with that code.

Comment: You want to go for a loop that checks if the value of username is equal to the cell above it, if so add the value to the right of that row, if not go for next row.